# What is the difference between 怀疑 and 疑惑?

Tags: meaning, difference

I have found the following definitions:

怀疑 [doubt; suspect; scepsis]

疑惑 [feel uncertain; be not convinced], and it is additionally defined as  "Puzzle" and "Unpeaceful"

From what I feel the former is more about skepticism, while the latter is more about uncertainty

Comment: ＂汉语动词３８０例＂has the pair 怀疑／疑心 but not 疑惑（all 3 in CIME), according to which "疑心" 和 ＂怀疑２。＂的意思相同，可以互换，where 怀疑２（cf. answers):王丽怀疑是有人敲门。＂怀疑＂在这儿是猜测别人做某事的意思。又例如：a。我怀疑今天要下雨。b。听口音，我怀疑他是广东人。＂怀疑＂表示猜测的意思时，通常不使用否定形式。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **怀疑** is a verb for '**to suspect**'

Example: 我**怀疑**他杀了他儿子 (I **suspect** he killed his son)

> **怀疑** is also a noun for **[suspicion](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/suspicion?s=t)** (*2.the state of mind or feeling of one who suspects*)

Example: 这只是我的**怀疑** (It is only my **suspicion**)

> **疑惑** is an adjective for '**[uncertain](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/uncertain?s=t)** (*2. not confident, assured, or free from hesitancy*); **puzzled**'

Example: 你这话使我感到**疑惑** (these words of yours make me feel **uncertain**)

> **疑惑** is also a noun for ' **doubt**; **[uncertainty](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/uncertainty)**; **puzzle**'

Example: 有**疑惑** (have **doubt**) ; 重重**疑惑** (layers upon layers of **uncertainty**); 这个**疑惑** (this **puzzle**)

> **嫌疑** is noun for '**[suspicion](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/suspicion)**' (*4.state of being suspected*)

Example:他有杀了他儿子的**嫌疑** (he is under the **suspicion** of killed his son)

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you've got a good handle on it.

Here's the entries as they appear in *Pocket Oxford*:

> ﻿**怀疑**
>
> <动 名> doubt, suspect
>
> 引起怀疑
>
> arouse suspicion
>
> 我怀疑他今天来不了
>
> I have a hunch that he won't be able to come today

> **疑惑**
>
> <动> feel uncertain, not be convinced
>
> 疑惑不解
>
> feel puzzled

I don't know where you get the meaning *unpeaceful* from for 疑惑, but other than that you're going in the right direction.